# Escape quotes on onclick metho

Tags: php, html, echo

I have click method generated by php echo. It does not render as it should be. It shows as in the attached image.

my code is

```
echo "<div class='col-sm-3' onclick='ViewItem('".$item['item_id']."')' style='cursor:pointer'>";
```

how can I escape the quotes to get the following

```
<div class='col-sm-3' onclick='ViewItem("1")' style='cursor:pointer'>
```

[image]

Comment: `onclick='ViewItem('` - the first single quote is the starting delimiter of your attribute value - so the next one is of course the ending delimiter. Everything coming after that is gibberish, that is not part of the onclick attributes's value any more.

Comment: Use the escape char \ on the quote \".

Comment: @JasonK I've tried 2 hours on that one. But it did not work. May be I don't know how to use it. Could you please explain how to achieve?

Comment: Also see [PHP heredoc](https://www.phptutorial.net/php-tutorial/php-heredoc/) for quote escaping solutions.

Answer (score 1):

We have all been there looking at code too long.

```
$item['item_id'] = '6';
echo "<div class='col-sm-3' onclick='ViewItem(\"".$item['item_id']."\")' style='cursor:pointer'>";
```

Output:

```
<div class='col-sm-3' onclick='ViewItem("6")' style='cursor:pointer'>
```